# Type deduction in Rust, how to do it brief

Tags: generics, rust

I am developing with rust-libp2p and I want to reuse a variable. for this reason, I am testing something like this:

```
let mut swarm =  {
    let mut behaviour = MyBehaviour {
        floodsub: libp2p::floodsub::Floodsub::new(self.local_peer_id.clone()),
        mdns: libp2p::mdns::Mdns::new().expect("Failed to create mDNS service"),
        node_manager: self.rc_node.clone(),
    };

    let floodsub_topic = libp2p::floodsub::TopicBuilder::new("chat").build();
    behaviour.floodsub.subscribe(floodsub_topic.clone());

    let transport = libp2p::build_development_transport(self.local_key.clone());
    libp2p::Swarm::new(transport, behaviour,self.local_peer_id.clone())
};
self.my_swarm: Swarm<_ , _> = swarm;
```

The problem of this is how to fill the `_` with the type classes definition... It seems simple, but these types has a large hierarchy to do this and the result is too complex:

```
self.my_swarm = Swarm<Transport<Output = (PeerId, impl core::muxing::StreamMuxer<OutboundSubstream = impl Send, Substream = impl Send, Error = impl Into<io::Error>> + Send + Sync), Error = impl error::Error + Send, Listener = impl Send, Dial = impl Send, ListenerUpgrade = impl Send> + Clone, NetworkBehaviour> = swarm;
```

It is not scalable and practical, does it exist some method to do it brief or to apply dynamic typing....??

**UPDATED**

My minimum example could be something like this:

```
struct InfoValue<V> {
    value: V,
    info: &'static str,
}

pub trait Info {
    fn get_info(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl Info for InfoValue<u32>  {
    fn get_info(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.info
    }
}

struct ImprovedPoint<T: Info> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

struct ContainerEx {
    improved_integer: ImprovedPoint<InfoValue<u32>>
}


fn main() {
    let impr_x = InfoValue{value: 5, info: "is a 5"};
    let impr_y = InfoValue{value: 10, info: "is a 10"};
    let improved_integer = ImprovedPoint{x: impr_x, y: impr_y};
    let container = ContainerEx{improved_integer: improved_integer};

}
```

The problem is here:

```
improved_integer: ImprovedPoint<InfoValue<u32>>
```

As far as I know, we must specify all the types. In this case, it is simple, two levels *InfoValue -> u32* but in real use cases, where we work with complex hierarchies, I would be great some dynamic type deduction.

Comment: Please consider adding a link to more complete code, or creating a [reprex]. There are too many unknown types etc in this code snippet.

Comment: I expect that you can use `_` to elide _parts_ of this type, even if you can't elide all of it. You may also find that you don't need to specify all of the associated types - OR you can specify the implementation of the trait instead of writing the trait and all of the constraints on its associated types - those would be fixed if you just gave a concrete type instead.